# PHP and JSON: Returning a suitable format

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, geolocation

I am trying to use google map direction API to map route connecting cities from the database. My problem is that I am stuck at a point I am supposed to return values from php script through json.
My data to map is inform of an array:

```
$data=array('chicago','new york','lebanon','maysvile','greenfield');
```

My intention is to return the following format from my data array.

```
var request = {
   origin:start, 
   destination:end,
   waypoints:[{
         location:"",
         stopover:true
   }],
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
}
```

This is how I got my start and destination: the first and last elements in the array:

```
$start=reset($data);     
$end=end($data);
```

Data to returned by php using json_encode()

```
    $response=array('origin'=>$start,'destination'=>$end,'travelMode'=>"google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING");
echo json_encode($response);
```

The format returned is not correct. Also I can't figure out how I should do the mid points. The mid points are all the values remaining after the $start and $end have been picked.
Any ideas is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: `google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING` is not a string (at least not a string with the value `'google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING'`). You need to use its value when creating your JSON.

Comment: How do I create/map the request with it included without excluding the other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = array(
    'origin' => array_shift($data),
    'destination' => array_pop($data),
    'waypoints' => array(),
    'travelMode' => 'DRIVING'
);
foreach($data as $wp) {
    $response['waypoints'][] = array('stopover' => true, 'location' => $wp);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Note that `array_shift` and `array_pop` modify the `$data` array!

The output of the script is:

```
{
    "origin": "chicago",
    "destination": "greenfield",
    "waypoints": [
        {
            "stopover": true,
            "location": "new york"
        },
        {
            "stopover": true,
            "location": "lebanon"
        },
        {
            "stopover": true,
            "location": "maysvile"
        }
    ],
    "travelMode": "DRIVING"
}
```

Comment: I like the way you have done for the waypoints, origin and destination but the final format is not correct. Here is the output:

Comment: {"origin":"GEORGETOWN KY 40324","destination":"GEORGETOWN KY 40324","waypoints":["Mantachie MS 38855"],"travelMode":"the value of google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING"}

Comment: Updated. Now it should do what you want.

Comment: note the braces like "" surrounding the origin parameter. That returns error in the javascript. How can we achieve this without the braces on parameters?

Comment: Do you mean the quotes? They are necessary. Otherwise it wouldn't be a string and not valid JSON.

Comment: Then I dont know if json is the best for this. Correct values are returned but we are mission in formatting. Here is my preview from chrome developers tool.

Comment: destination: "GEORGETOWN KY 40324"
origin: "GEORGETOWN KY 40324"
travelMode: "google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING"
waypoints: [{stopover:true, location:Mantachie MS 38855}]
0: {stopover:true, location:Mantachie MS 38855}
location: "Mantachie MS 38855"
stopover: true

Comment: Note we are missing commas at the end of each parameters.  like it should be origin:start, 
   destination:end,....

Comment: The developer tools display objects in a nice way, usually as a tree. If you want to see the JSON, have a look at `JSON.stringify(obj)` or the raw output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the response back from PHP, it will be a string, containing JSON formatted data.

You will need to use:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(stringOfJson);
```

To convert it to a JSON object.

If you want a PHP representation of the data, why not create an object in PHP to represent it:

```
class RouteInformation 
{
    public $Origin;
    public $Destination;
    public $Waypoints;
    public $TravelMode;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->Waypoints = array();
    }
}
```

You can then serialize this object to JSON and it will be in the format you require.

```
$response = new RouteInformation();
$response->Origin = array_shift($data);
$response->Destination = array_pop($data);
$response->TravelMode = 'DRIVING';

foreach($data as $wp) {
    $response->Waypoints[] = array('stopover' => true, 'location' => $wp);
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

You could go a step further and create a Waypoint class to represent each Waypoint in the array.

Comment: I think he already does that or has a library do it for him. Otherwise he wouldn't get a "non-json" representation when viewing it in developer tools.

Comment: @ThiefMaster you are right we already have it. How can we format the result we have to return something like origin:'origin name',destination:'destination name',....  Note the commas (,)